# Passing Nulls from Excel to SQL

Tags: sql, vba, excel, null

I'm using a VBA Script to update a table in SQL, so far it works perfectly. The problem is when handling null values. Because the VBA script loops until the first column ends, some values are null in the worksheet, but they are placed as zeros in sql.

In Excel:

```
    Name     Last name      Age    
    daniel   mtz            22
    jose     mtz            25
    John     doe
```

Final result in SQL:

```
    Name     Last name      Age    
    daniel   mtz            22
    jose     mtz            25
    John     doe            0
```

Any thoughts on how I can tell the Macro or SQL to read them as null and not zero?

P.S, programming each column in sql to place null in the corresponding value is not an option, because this table will be changing constantly and I could have all columns filled, or just some, etc.

[UPDATE] Here is the code for the VBA:

```
Sub Macro_CargarSQL()

'VARIABLES
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim iRowNo As Integer
'Column variables
Dim sname, slastname, sage As String

'CONECTION TO SERVER Y BD
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Termxgesvsql07\vfsitesamn;Initial Catalog=DW_PLCO;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
'Import into SQL
With Sheets("test")
    'Start row 2
    iRowNo = 2
    'Delete previous
    conn.Execute "delete from table"

    'Loop for insert
    Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        sname = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
        slastname = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
        sage = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)

        conn.Execute "insert into dbo.table (name, lastname,age ) values ('" & sname & "', '" & slastname & "', '" & sage & "')"
        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
    Loop
End With
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Easier to answer if you show your actual code.

Comment: .... what is the VBA you are using to populate the database with? One approach is parameters and only including the parameters if the value is non-null.

Comment: @enderland, I added the VBA code at the end. Thanks!

Comment: @eflores, instead of telling the loop to terminate when the cell is empty, use VBA to find the last row.  Is A always populated?  Then do lastRow = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row , and replace your Do loop with a For iRowNo = 2 to lastRow loop.  Or if you dont know which column will contain the last row, just do that for all columns and pick the highest value.

Comment: I don't know if that's a real connection string or not, but you should probably remove that from the code example.

Answer (score 0):

One way I've done this is to create two SQL strings and do checks on the actually values.

You can do this as follows (generally this is a lot easier if you have an array as you can write an iteration through your values/fieldnames).

```
Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
    sName = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
    slastname = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
    sage = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)

    Dim sqlStrStart As String
    Dim sqlStrValues As String
    Dim sqlStrFull As String

    sqlStrStart = "insert into dbo.table ("
    sqlStrValues = " values ("

    'build string dynamically (generally I do this using parameters, but this will work)
    If sName <> "" Then
        sqlStrStart = sqlStrStart + "name,"
        sqlStrValues = sqlStrValues + sName & ","
    End If
    If slastname <> "" Then
        sqlStrStart = sqlStrStart + "lastname,"
        sqlStrValues = sqlStrValues + slastname & ","
    End If
    If sName <> "" Then
        sqlStrStart = sqlStrStart + "age,"
        sqlStrValues = sqlStrValues + sage & ","
    End If

    'remove last comma
    sqlStrStart = Left(sqlStrStart, Len(sqlStrStart) - 1)
    sqlStrValues = Left(sqlStrValues, Len(sqlStrValues) - 1)

    'close parenthesis
    sqlStrStart = sqlStrStart & ")"
    sqlStrValues = sqlStrValues & ")"

    'combine
    sqlStrFull = sqlStrStart + sqlStrValues + ";"


    conn.Execute sqlStrFull
    iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a function that inspects whether a cell value is empty or not.  When empty, output should be `"null"`, but when not, enclose the value in between single quotes.

This function can also be used so you can escape values that has single quote in it (such as "O'Brien").  Otherwise, in your current code, you'll encounter a SQL error.

Here's the function:

```
Function toSQL(s)
  If s = "" Then toSQL = "null" Else toSQL = "'" & Replace(s, "'", "''") & "'"
End Function
```

And here's the replacement Insert statement:

```
conn.Execute "insert into dbo.table (name, lastname,age ) values (" & toSQL(sname) & ", " & toSQL(slastname) & ", " & toSQL(sage) & ")"
```

If you consistently call the `toSQL` function, and also consistently define the column in the SQL database as nullable, you'll be set.  If the data type is numeric, you may not want to call `toSQL` though.

Comment: This still doesn't protect against SQL-Injection, you will want to use SQL Commands.

Answer (score 0):

Use this when setting a `null` value in Excel VBA, and pass that to the SQL parameter's value.

```
DBNull.Value
```